Уменьшение размера git репозитория
Есть некий git репозиторий в битбакет и на локале, им пользуются несколько человек, в результате репозиторий стал занимать около 6 Гб из за обилия старых коммитов, ветка одна master, из нее файлы утетают на несколько серверов, так что должны быть именно ветка master.Сами файлы занимают пару сотню Мб
Вопрос: Как уменьшить размер репозитория? (например удалить старые коммиты оставив только самый свежий)

https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-Git-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0

Прежде, чем резать репозиторий, убедитесь, что вы правильно определили размер репозитория, как его сообщает битбакет, а не просто просмотрели размер папки в проводнике. Далее, следует убедиться, что в репозиторий не попадали ненужные файлы, такие как ассеты, кеши IDE, артефакты сборки и т.п. Вопросы про удаление файлов и/или коммитов из истории уже были.
